# 2D frame analysis by open-source Lua code

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, frame

There are great apps for 2D frame analysis like the one mentioned here:

https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/50967/15178

I'm just wondering if anyone knows an open-source Lua code for 2D frame analysis.

I'm focused on Lua programming language, since Lua Scripting for TI-Nspire™ is possible. And I have this device:

[image: TI-Nspire™ calculator]